# Inserting values in temporary table from real table by using stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server

How do I insert values in temporary table from real table by using stored procedure?

When I'm executing this code in SQL Server it is showing me the correct result:

```
SELECT 
    Toy_Image, Toy_Name, Anime_Image, Anime_Name,
    Toy_Distributor_Image, Toy_Distributor
INTO #Temp
FROM Toy
```

But  when I'm trying to execute this code in SQL Server through stored procedure, it is not giving me any result and it is returning null value:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE AddToCart
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT 
        Toy_Image, Toy_Name, Anime_Image, Anime_Name, 
        Toy_Distributor_Image, Toy_Distributor
    INTO #Temp
    FROM Toy
END
```

I need help to solve this problem

Comment: [How to Share Data between Stored Procedures - Erland Sommarskog](http://www.sommarskog.se/share_data.html)  This article tackles two related questions:

    How can I use the result set from one stored procedure in another, also expressed as How can I use the result set from a stored procedure in a SELECT statement?
    How can I pass a table data in a parameter from one stored procedure to another?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I created the table Toy and inserted a test record. The following stored procedure works for me.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE AddToCart
AS
BEGIN
SELECT Toy_Image,Toy_Name,Anime_Image,Anime_Name,Toy_Distributor_Image,Toy_Distributor
INTO #Temp
FROM Toy

SELECT Toy_Image,Toy_Name,Anime_Image,Anime_Name,Toy_Distributor_Image,Toy_Distributor
FROM #Temp
END
```

I could see the test record inserted into #Temp when I run the procedure.

Maybe you need to give more details.

Comment: Bingol ... Thanks a lot bro, I tried your code and now it is working

Comment: @user2685850, I am glad it helped you.

Answer (score 1):

Temporary tables created within the scope of a stored procedure are implicitly dropped then the stored procedure finishes.

If you want to load data into a temp table in a proc that is available afterward, create the temp table beforehand on the same connection and use `INSERT` instead of `SELECT...INTO` in the proc.

Alternatively, you could use a permanent table, keyed by a session id. This is a better approach to maintain state for a "shopping cart" application in order to avoid keeping a persistent connection open. You'll need to clean up abandoned sessions, though.

Answer (score 0):

The temporary table that you create in the stored procedure has a *scope* only of the stored procedure.  That is, it is automatically deleted when the stored procedure has finished execution.

This is actually considered a *feature* of SQL Server.  You can use temporary tables in a stored procedure and not have to worry about deleting them.

If you want the "temporary" table to persist, either use a global temporary table or a real table.